# pandas merge indicator with dataframe name instead of 'right_only'

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to make the `indicator` option of `pd.merge` display dataframe names instead of "left_only" and "right_only"? i.e. display "df1_only" instead of "left_only"? I know it can be done with the code below but I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', indicator='check')
df['check'] = df['check'].str.replace('left_only','df1_only').str.replace('right_only','df2_only')
```

Comment: A python object can be bound to many names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A python object can be bound to many names. In fact, the names of the references to your dataframes within the function is likely something like `left` and `right`, not `df1` and `df2`. Pandas has no way of knowing what name you want to use because it can't look into the caller namespace (without jumping through some spectacular hoops at least).

The solution you propose is the correct one. Simply replace `left` and `right` with any arbitrary strings of choice.